# Getting XMMS2 to connect to streaminig audio

Tags: music, streaming, xmms

I've decided to resurrect GKrellm on my Ubuntu 16.04 box as I liked the
various options for monitoring and other things it does. I installed
the GKrellmms plug-in as when previously running it I liked the option
of streaming live audio with it. Now however I'm having a problem
getting that to work. I want to stream from this site
http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/oggflac/live.pls?service=ac
When the link is highlighted on the site and "save link as" is selected it's saved as a .pls file (playlist). The link is then shown as
http://icecast-beta.timlradio.co.uk/absoluteclassicrock.ogg
Per the XMMS2 WIKI at https://github.com/xmms2/wiki/wiki/Using-the-application

```
Listen to a shoutcast stream (assuming curl plugin is installed) 
using the direct url (ie NOT a playlist file, but the url inside 
the playlist file, the playlist importing code is currently disabled). 
If you don't require a proxy skip the "config" lines:
xmms2 server config curl.proxyaddress your.proxy.address.com:1080  
xmms2 server config curl.useproxy 1  xmms2 add http://207.200.96.225:8020 xmms2 play
```

I'm 'assuming' that listening to an icecast stream would be the same or similar to a shoutcast stream I entered this at the xmms2> prompt:

```
xmms2> add http://icecast-beta.timlradio.co.uk/absoluteclassicrock.ogg
```

then xmms2> play - however, I get no audio. The XMMS2d log at ~/.cache/xmms2 shows:

```
17:17:58 ERROR: ../src/xmms/xform.c:1341: Couldn't set up chain for 'http://icecast-beta.timlradio.co.uk/absoluteclassicrock.ogg' (5)
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxcb_connection_has_error() returned true
```

I can however load up music from my ~/Music folder into a playlist from the gxmms2 frontend. I can load the tracks that are there. The xmms2d log shows

```
17:34:22  INFO: ../src/xmms/xform.c:1364: Successfully setup chain for 'file:///home/chris/Music /BENT+OUT+OF+SHAPE+-+RAINBOW+-+1983+-+RAINBOW+-+03+-+Fool+For+The+Night+.mp3'   (4) containing file:magic:id3v2:magic:mad:segment
```

Pressing xmms2> play at the prompt will play the above selection. NOTE: I can put the URL http://icecast-beta.timlradio.co.uk into Audacious and it plays just fine.

I've installed the xmms2 plug-ins from here - https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xmms2-plugin-all into /usr/lib/xmms2.

Another option I tried is I converted the URL into an IP with the port for icecast added - http://34.244.146.50:443 still nothing.

```
09:49:01 ERROR: ../src/xmms/xform.c:1341: Couldn't set up chain for 'http://34.244.146.50:443' (5)
09:56:23 ERROR: ../src/xmms/xform.c:1341: Couldn't set up chain for 'http://34.244.146.50:443' (5)
```

I hope this isn't too confusing and that I've added enough information to possibly get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The approach described [in this website](http://blog.xmms2.org/2011/05/world-ipv6-day-with-xmms2.html) worked fine for me.

OS: Lubuntu 20.04, with PulseAudio

To summarize:

1. Start xmms2, and set the environment variable core.ipcsocket by running

```
xmms2> server config core.ipcsocket "unix:///tmp/xmms-ipc-<your_username>;tcp://[::]:9667"
```

or by editing the core.ipcsocket tag in ~/.config/xmms2/xmms2.conf

2. Verify xmms2 can see the change by running

```
xmms2> server config core.ipcsocket
core.ipcsocket = unix:///tmp/xmms-ipc-<your_username>;tcp://[::]:9667
```

and ensuring the output comes out as above, with no errors.

3. xmms2 must show the opened port in netstat on a command prompt, now

```
netstat -an | grep 9667
tcp6       0      0 :::9667         :::*            LISTEN
```

4. That was it, pretty much

```
xmms2> add http://netpd.org:8010/64k.mp3
xmms2> play
```

had audio pop out with not much fuss. Not sure if all this effort can be short circuited by just installing a client like lxmusic, which seems to be the latest stable xmms2 client.